# How to save the results of a select expression as a variable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, subquery

In the following Postgresql sql, is there a way to save `mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at` as a variable so I don't have to repeat myself?

```sql
SELECT 
    to_char(mo.created_at,'MM-YYYY') AS month,
    mo.sku_key as sku,
    c.name,
    COUNT(*) as total,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at < interval '3 days') as three_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at > interval '3 days' and mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at <= interval '6 days') as six_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at > interval '6 days' and mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at <= interval '9 days') as nine_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at > interval '9 days') as ten_days,
    min(mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at),
    max(mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at),
    percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at) as median,
    avg(mo.delivered_at - mo.created_at) as average
FROM medication_order mo
LEFT JOIN subscription s ON s.id=mo.subscription_id
LEFT JOIN condition c on s.condition_id = c.id
WHERE 
    mo.status = 'DELIVERED' AND 
    mo.payment_preference = 'INSURANCE' AND
    mo.created_at > '2020-01-01' AND
    mo.delivered_at IS NOT null AND
    mo.sku_key != 'manual_order_sku'
GROUP BY month, mo.sku_key, c.name
```

Comment: You can reorganize to use a CTE or a subquery.

Comment: Or, if you use that often, make it a generated column which can then be indexed. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: You group by `c.name`. Presumably a lengthy text column? Is `condition.name` defined `UNIQUE`? (Probably should be.)  Then you can make the query a bit cheaper ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, it is a text field. Not unique, now that I look at it.

Comment: So you can have two *distinct* conditions with the same name? Wouldn't `GROUP BY` like you have it produce misleading results?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice I believe the front end creates a unique slug based on the name, so there is an effective constraint on this field. It's not the best design, but it's what I have to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute the derived value in a subquery or CTE as has been suggested.

But there is more. This should be faster (and correct). And can be sorted properly, too:

```sql
SELECT
    to_char(mo.month,'MM-YYYY') AS month,  -- optionally prettify
    mo.sku,
    s.condition_id,  -- I added this to make the result unambiguous
    (SELECT name FROM condition WHERE id = s.condition_id) AS condition_name,
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.my_interval < interval '3 days') AS three_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.my_interval > interval '3 days' AND mo.my_interval <= interval '6 days') AS six_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.my_interval > interval '6 days' AND mo.my_interval <= interval '9 days') AS nine_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.my_interval > interval '9 days') AS ten_days,
    min(mo.my_interval),
    max(mo.my_interval),
    percentile_disc(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mo.my_interval) AS median,
    avg(mo.my_interval) AS average
FROM  (
   SELECT
       date_trunc('month', mo.created_at) AS month,         -- faster, keeps ORDER
       delivered_at - created_at          AS my_interval,   -- your core request
       sku_key                            AS sku
   FROM   medication_order mo
   WHERE  status = 'DELIVERED'                              -- filter early
   AND    payment_preference = 'INSURANCE'
   AND    created_at > '2020-01-01'
   AND    delivered_at IS NOT NULL
   AND    sku_key <> 'manual_order_sku'
   ) mo
LEFT   JOIN subscription s ON s.id = mo.subscription_id
GROUP  BY mo.month, mo.sku, s.condition_id  -- GROUP BY unique ID! Correct - and cheaper, too
ORDER  BY mo.month, mo.sku, s.condition_id; -- my addition: sorting by date works across years, 'MM-YYYY' does not
```

Aside: `condition.name` should probably be `UNIQUE`. And "name" is almost never a good name.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was wondering about the sort issue I was having.

Answer (score 2):

You could just compute the information in a subquery when selecting from the table:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(mo.created_at,'MM-YYYY') AS month,
    mo.sku_key as sku,
    c.name,
    COUNT(*) as total,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivery_interval < interval '3 days') as three_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivery_interval > interval '3 days' and mo.delivery_interval <= interval '6 days') as six_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivery_interval > interval '6 days' and mo.delivery_interval <= interval '9 days') as nine_days,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mo.delivery_interval > interval '9 days') as ten_days,
    min(mo.delivery_interval),
    max(mo.delivery_interval),
    percentile_disc(0.5) within group (order by mo.delivery_interval) as median,
    avg(mo.delivery_interval) as average
FROM (
    SELECT mo.*, mo.delivery_interval delivery_interval   --> here
    FROM medication_order
) mo
LEFT JOIN subscription s ON s.id=mo.subscription_id
LEFT JOIN condition c on s.condition_id = c.id
WHERE 
    mo.status = 'DELIVERED' AND 
    mo.payment_preference = 'INSURANCE' AND
    mo.created_at > '2020-01-01' AND
    mo.delivered_at IS NOT null AND
    mo.sku_key != 'manual_order_sku'
GROUP BY month, mo.sku_key, c.name
```